# undefined method `to_date' for nil:NilClass on Heroku App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, activerecord

I have error undefined method `to_date' for nil:NilClass on my heroku server but everything work in local, i dont know how i can fix it

my helper where i call "to_date"

module BiensHelper

```
def sell_time(sell_date)
    time = Time.now.to_s
    time = time.to_date
    delai = time - sell_date.to_date
    delai.round
end
```

end

The view where i call my helper

```
    <% @biens.each do |bien| %>
    <h3>
    <%= bien[:name] %> <br>
    <%= bien[:adress] %> <br>
    <%= bien[:bien_type] %> <br>
    <%= bien[:url] %> <br>
    <%= bien[:latitude] %> <br>
    <%= bien[:longitude] %> <br>
    Vendu il y a <%= sell_time(bien.sell_date) %> jours<br>
    <%= link_to "Modifier", edit_bien_path(bien), class: "btn btn-warning" %> <br>
    <%= link_to "X", bien_path(bien), method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger" %> <br>
</h3>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Your error is showing that `sell_date` is passing nil value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is showing that `sell_date` is passing nil value at line `delai = time - sell_date.to_date`

You can ignore this kind of error like

```
def sell_time(sell_date)
  if sell_date.present?
    delai = Date.today - sell_date.to_date
    delai.round
  end
end
```

And

```
time = Time.now.to_s
time = time.to_date
```

Here you are taking `Time.now` and then converting this to `to_date` instead this you can directly use `Date.today`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error here :

```
delai = time - sell_date.to_date
```

sell_date is nil for your one of record. Please check heorku db. Run `heroku run rails db` from your console.

Or you can open rails console like this `heroku run rails console`.

Change code to :

```
def sell_time(sell_date)
  time = Time.now.to_s
  time = time.to_date
  if sell_date.present?
    delai = time - sell_date.to_date
    delai.round
  end
end
```

Function will return sell time to current time if sell_date is nil. But in my view you should fix db. and write correct values to db.